# Dropbox - How to list files inside directory

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

Any idea on how to list all the files inside a directoy in Dropbox via the PHP api?

Partially the function: [searchFileNames](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.Client.html#_searchFileNames) does what I need with the following code:

```
$dbxClient = new dbx\Client("<access_token>", "PHP-Example/1.0");
$result = $dbxClient->searchFileNames($path_dir, "<some_common_text>");
```

but this function doesn't offer any wildcard on the second parameter where I could specify: "*" in order to list all the files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

```
$dbxClient->getMetadataWithChildren($path_dir)
```