# Get names of files contained in Dropbox directory

Tags: matlab, dropbox

I'm in need to read a large number of files from a permanent Dropbox webpage.

The reading part is fine, but I'm having troubles finding a way to list all the files contained within.
To be more precise, I would need something like

```
files = dir([url_to_Dropbox_directory,'*.file_extension']);
```

returning the names of all the files.
I've found an [example in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167419/dropbox-how-to-list-files-inside-directory), but nothing for MATLAB. Using `dir` was just an example, I'm looking for any solution to this problem.

How can I get the file list from a permanent Dropbox webpage?

Comment: Are the Dropbox files synced to your computer? Then you can just use the path instead of a URL.

Comment: Unfortunately no, there are way too many files to download locally.

Comment: Then that's not going to work out of the box. `dir` supports S3 and Azure storage as far as I know, but it won't support dropbox

Comment: `dir` was just an example, I'm looking for any (if there is!) solution to get the list of files contained. (Also updated in the question)

Comment: You can use the [`dropbox API`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder), and pass the curl command in the [`webwrite`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webwrite.html) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Dropbox API where you can acces that data by a http request. "file-list-folder" is the specific endpoint that you are looking for.

Here is the documentation for it:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder

In addition you could use the SDK for PHP (or others programming languages). I have used the SDK for JS and it's easy and works well.

PHP SDK:

https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/